# Subalgebra of Clifford algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, clifford-algebras

Let $Cl(V\oplus V^{*})$ the Clifford algebra of $V\oplus V^{*}$ with natural pairing. 
How can check a subset $ Λ^{•} (V^{*}) $ is a subalgebra of Clifford algebra $Cl(V\oplus V^{*})$?

Comment: Is $A$ a Clifford algebra? Or are you considering a Clifford algebra over $A$? What is the definition/construction of $S$ that does not automatically identify it as subalgebra?

Comment: Checking for a subalgebra is always the same: check closedness under all operations. Are you having difficulties with a particular set $S$ and a particular operation?

Comment: Sorry about that i edite this question now

Comment: @lisyarus please check the edited version

Comment: What is $\Lambda^\bullet$? The exterior algebra?

Comment: @lisyarus yes it is exterior algebra

Comment: It is usually denoted just $\Lambda(V^*)$. What makes you think it is a subalgebra? The only thing I know about these is that $Cl(V\oplus V^*) \cong \operatorname{End}(\Lambda(V)) \cong \operatorname{End}(\Lambda(V^*))$.

Comment: @lisyarus because it is related to $V$ and $V^{*}$ is maximal isotropic with natural pairing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The natural quadratic form on $V\oplus V^*$ is

$$Q(v, \phi) = \phi(v)$$

where $v\in V$ and $\phi \in V^*$. It is an example of [hyperbolic/split/metabolic quadratic space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotropic_quadratic_form).

Elements of $V^*$ are naturally embedded into $V\oplus V^*$ via

$$\phi \mapsto (0, \phi)$$

and the value of the quadratic form on those is

$$Q(0,\phi) = \phi(0) = 0$$

Thus, the embedded copy of $V^*$ is a subspace with zero quadratic form. The Clifford algebra of such a space is, by definition, the exterior algebra. Since Clifford algebra is functorial, embedding of quadratic spaces gives algebra embeddings; thus, the Clifford algebra of $V^*$ with a zero quadratic form, which is $\Lambda(V^*)$, is embedded into $\operatorname{Cl}(V \oplus V^*)$. This is exactly the subalgebra generated by the embedded copy of $V^*$ via the diagram of embeddings

$$
\begin{matrix}
V^* & \rightarrow & V \oplus V^* \\
\downarrow & & \downarrow \\
\Lambda(V^*) & \rightarrow & \operatorname{Cl}(V \oplus V^*)
\end{matrix}
$$

The same reasoning applies to $V$ embedded into $V \oplus V^*$ and $\Lambda(V)$ embedded into $\operatorname{Cl}(V \oplus V^*)$.

Comment: Thank you for clarification

Comment: @Fidelgh. You are welcome.

Comment: Pity the question does not fully define the Clifford algebra, but the natural quadratic form given in the answer is, well, the natural way to complete the definition.